# Outlook distribution list hanging up on contact items query

Tags: vba, outlook

I was working from some [tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) to learn to make some macros for Outlook. I have this subroutine that gets hung up with a `Type mismatch` error. Upon stepping through error handling after `Stop` and `Resume` it goes back to `Next` and finishes the query.

Looking through the result set in Immediate, one item is missing which is actually a distribution mailing list instead of a normal contact. I moved the mailing list out of my contacts for testing, and the error did not happen.

I do plan on having other mailing lists as well, as this is for work. Is there a workaround like some way to escape it, other than just saving them somewhere else?

Here is the code:

```
Sub ContactName()

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    Dim ContactsFolder As Folder
    Set ContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
    MsgBox ("Contacts found: " & ContactsFolder.Items.Count)

    Dim Contact As ContactItem
    For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
        Debug.Print Contact.CompanyName
    Next
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Stop
    Resume

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the `Mailing List` item is not a `Contact` and therefore `For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items` will fail due to not being able to cast to `Contact`. One alternative would be to use a `FOR` loop rather than `FOR EACH`. Then you should be able to iterate thru the `Items` and test what type of Item you have and cast accordingly before accessing its properties.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, that or I wouldn't know how to write it with a `FOR` loop (bare-bones newbie here) but if you're able to test on your machine with a mailing list present in contacts and post the working code, I'll be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to distinguish between Lists and Contacts, you can alter your code to the following:

```
Sub ContactName()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

Dim ContactsFolder As Folder
Set ContactsFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts)
MsgBox ("Contacts found: " & ContactsFolder.Items.Count)

Dim Contact As ContactItem
Dim distList As DistListItem
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To ContactsFolder.Items.Count

    If TypeOf ContactsFolder.Items(i) Is DistListItem Then
      Set distList = ContactsFolder.Items(i)
      Debug.Print distList.DLName
    ElseIf TypeOf ContactsFolder.Items(i) Is ContactItem Then
      Set contact = ContactsFolder.Items(i)
      Debug.Print contact.FullName
    Else
      Debug.Print "Item is something else"
    End If

Next i
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Stop
    Resume

End Sub
```

Note, I changed the property I'm accessing from CompanyName to FullName for my tests as I didn't have CompanyName for all my contacts.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim Contact As ContactItem
For Each Contact In ContactsFolder.Items
    Debug.Print Contact.CompanyName
Next
```

When you defined `Contact as ContactItem` you are telling VBA *exactly* what type of thing it should find in `Items`. This works great, only if all items in the ContactsFolder are actually ContactItems.

In other words, you are specifically going through all items in a bag but specifically making each of them an Apple - but when you encounter an Irange, VBA throws an error.

What I generally do in this situation is instead of saying that I want to go through all apples in a bag, I want to go through each *item* in a bag, so something like:

```
Dim mContact 'by not dimensioning it you basically allow mContact to become whatever type each item is 
For Each mContact In ContactsFolder.Items
    Debug.Print mContact.CompanyName
Next
```

Note that I changed your name to `mContact` because it's probable `Contact` is a keyword in VBA and it's sometimes better to not deal with this.

This above will still cause errors because any mContact which does not have a `.CompanyName` attribute.

What you can do is the following:

```
Dim mContact 
For Each mContact In ContactsFolder.Items
    if mContact.Class = olContact then
        Debug.Print mContact.CompanyName
    Else
        Debug.Print "Not a Contact! Actually a :" & typename(mContact)
    End if
Next
```

This will check for whether the object you are iterating through (the fruit from the bag) is actually an "apple" first, and if not, tell you what type of fruit it is.